# Programatically clicking a certain position in Google Slides

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Is it possible to click a certain position in Google Slides? I tried creating dispatchEvent inside of content scripts that was injected by Chrome Extension, but it looks it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: Works for me with `mousedown`: document.elementFromPoint(119, 632).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true, screenX: 764, screenY: 693, clientX: 119, clientY: 632})). Consider add your [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.

Comment: It worked! You helped me a lot! Thank you!